# Take a certain amount of days off the current date and print with certain date format

Tags: swift, date, datetime, nsdateformatter

How would I take a certain amount of days (take away one day) off the current date and print with certain date format to the console.

I'm currently using:

```
print((Calendar.current as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date(), options: [])!)
```

Which prints the date and time as:

> yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS +0000

But I want it to print like:

> dd-MM-yyyy

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Why are you using `NSCalendar`? Just use `Calendar` and its methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**swift 3.0 version**

```
let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
if let yesterday = yesterday {
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: yesterday))
}else{
    print("Date incorrectly manipulated")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's best to break that into a few more easily readable/maintainable lines. First, calculate the date you want, then apply a date formatter.

```
let yesterday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(yesterday))
```

Comment: You should use DateFormatter instead of NSDateFormatter in Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use fixed format for `Date` format strings. Because you might have users from around the world and they don't see dates in the same way.

Rather you should use template format. You just specify which components you want to show and their order like:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
// dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "bn-BD") // Enable this line only at the time of your debugging/testing
dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "ddMMyyyy",
                                                options: 0,
                                                locale: dateFormatter.locale)

let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())
if let date = date {
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(dateString)
}
```

> You shouldn't set your `locale` by yourself. It's done by the
>   framework. You should only set your `locale` manually only at the time
>   of testing your app.

In the above example I'm using `Locale` as `"bn-BD"` which means **Bangla in Bangladesh**. You can find your a list of locales [here](https://gist.github.com/ndbroadbent/588fefab8e0f1b459fcec8181b41b39c)